# Spring WS: Handle connection refused and client timeout exceptions

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I can't seem to find proper solution to this. I would want to handle and display different message to the user depending on what happened. I'm using Spring WS and calling `marshalSendAndReceive`. On the returning service method at the moment I would simply `catch (WebServiceIOException e)`, problem is that this exception is thrown by both Connection refused (wrong credentials) and when query takes longer than specified by client side (timeout)? Is there any proper way of handling these two without providing one general message that "something went wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebServiceTemplate` does its hard work in the method `doSendAndReceive`, where there is `try...catch` block and comprehensive error-handling. One of them is `triggerAfterCompletion(int interceptorIndex, MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex)`, which delegates to the injected `ClientInterceptor`.

So, you just need to implement properly `afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex)` to throw the appropriate business exception.

Comment: I'm afraid my Spring WS library in current project is a bit older and doesn't provide such behavior.

Comment: Well, otherwise you should extract `cause` from that `WebServiceIOException` and do the logic regarding each case. That's because `WebServiceTemplate` does this: `throw new WebServiceIOException("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to implement `ClientInterception` class

Another way is just catching general `Exception` class on where you send a request to web serice:

```
try {
  webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
} catch(Exception e){
   log.error("your custom message");
}
```